# What is Vcc-2 referring to in the Texas Instruments Tech Sheet for the SN74AS138?

Tags: datasheet

Total noob here.

The tech sheet can be found here:  http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74as138.pdf

In the V<sub>OH</sub> parameter for the SN74AS138 on page 5, it states that it's MIN is V<sub>CC</sub>-2.

What does that mean?  What is referring to?  Is it referring to the actual V<sub>CC</sub> minus 2 volts?  So 2.5V for V<sub>CC</sub> = 4.5V?

Here's the snippet I'm talking about:

[image: Snippet from datasheet]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a simple sum.

It refers to the output voltage when an output is HIGH (\$V_{OH}\$) as a minimum (it's in the MIN column) of 2 volts below \$V_{CC}\$, so if \$V_{CC} = 5V\$ then \$V_{OH}\$ will be *at least* 3V.

For CMOS you will often see something like \$0.6V_{CC}\$, where the value is 60% of the \$V_{CC}\$ value.

Answer (score 2):

It refers to the pin diagram on the first page, where Vcc is pin 16.

On page 4 of the datasheet, you see:

[image]

So it's the supply voltage of the IC.

Also see this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IC_power-supply_pin - excerpt:

> Typical supply pin labeling:
>
> V<sub>CC</sub> / V<sub>DD</sub> / V<sub>+</sub> / V<sub>S+</sub> : Positive supply voltage
>   V<sub>EE</sub> / V<sub>SS</sub> / V<sub>−</sub> / V<sub>S−</sub> : Negative supply voltage

And exactly, V<sub>CC</sub> - 2 refers to 'the supply voltage minus two volts'.